# CSS: Is box-reflect (or an alternative) compatible with IE10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

So I have the following line in my CSS:

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(70%, transparent), to(white));
```

This renders correctly in Chrome, as you would expect. I am wondering if there is a similar option for IE. I tried just dropping the webkit prefix, but that doesn't do the trick.

Checking http://html5please.com/ says to avoid using box-reflect - but the last time that feature was updated was more than a year ago.

Checking http://www.xhtml-lab.com/css/create-reflection-effect-using-css3 shows an alternative to box-reflect, but doesn't seem as elegant, and the author says at the end of the article that the solution doesn't work with IE, and that she herself is looking for a better solution. That one is over two years old.

Checking http://caniuse.com suggests box-reflect is not supported on IE at all - which does not fill me with hope. But I can't find a date, and will therefore pretend it's out of date for sake of this discussion :-p.

Comment: You may refer this example, which provides alternative to the box-reflect

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/cross-browser-css-reflections-glows-and-blurs/

Comment: Ichigo - TBH, I did see that page before I posted. I just have a hard time following that guy's example. It seems like he's got everything but the kitchen sink in there. It also seems to rely on an external svg file, which may introduce the same performance problem I was hoping to avoid by excluding js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no box reflect property for IE
But I have done a workaround to make it work in IE

```
<style type="text/css">
    #imgmask
    {
     -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); 
     -moz-transform: scaleY(-1); 
     -ms-transform: scaleY(-1); 
     -o-transform: scaleY(-1); 
     transform: scaleY(-1); 
     filter: flipv; 
     opacity:0.20; 
     filter: alpha(opacity='20');
   }
</style>

<div id="Div1">
<img src="Images/Photo.jpg" alt="Photos" height="200" width="200" />
</div>   
<div id="imgmask">
<img src="Images/Photo.jpg" alt="Photos" height="200" width="200" />
</div>
```

Thanks
AB

Comment: AB - That does indeed produce _nearly_ the results I was looking for, and a very clean implementation to boot! Can this be done with a gradient instead of the opacity filter? The gradient would make the reflection "shorter" - the opacity filter gives a complete reflection, which has its uses, just not what I need at the moment.