# Recreating webkit-box-reflect in ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
-webkit-box-reflect:
    below 0px 
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from( transparent ), color-stop(0.7, transparent), to( rgba(50,50,50,0.7) ) 
);
```

and after reading some of the question on the stack I have this code:

```
transform: scaleY(-1); 
filter: flipv; 
opacity:0.20; 
filter: alpha(opacity='20');
```

from this answer:
[Other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499332/css-is-box-reflect-or-an-alternative-compatible-with-ie10)

but this throws me parse error `RuntimeError: error evaluating function`alpha`: undefined is not a function`

in this line:
`filter: alpha(opacity='20');`

Comment: As SW4 has already said it, IE11 would throw these errors for non-standard css which was used in IE8-. Lose the `filter:()` lines, and include them as a conditional stylesheet if you want to support older IEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually dont need to use `filter: alpha(opacity='20');` if you are using IE11, [**this is for IE8 to support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity) the `opacity` setting you already have.

> Transparency for elements in IE8 and older can be achieved using the
>   proprietary "filter" property

This is also true for `filter: flipv;` which isnt necessary given the fact you have `transform: scaleY(-1);`

Incidentally, depending on if you are using a preprocessor (which the runtime error suggests), and which- you may also consider removing the `'` surrounding the alpha values, leaving:

`filter: alpha(opacity=20);`